# I am getting errors on connecting to remote heroku postgresql database

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy

I was working on my project that was using remote heroku postgresql database, that was working fine. Actually, I was using the sqlalchemy library to connect to remote database and I was also used to queries that remote database through my Ubuntu terminal by using **psql name_of_remote_database_url** command. But after sometime it is giving me a bundle of errors.[image: While connecting to remote database through command psql followed by database url giving me a bunch of errors]

And my project was on flask web application now, I am getting errors from this also.
enter image description here
[image: Error on my flask web application.]

I tried so much but I failed so, that's why I am posting my question here! If anyone knows then plz explain!

pg_hba.config something looks like this

[image]

Comment: Please post your `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: I added that too you can checkout above. I take pic of this /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf, may be 12 is a version?

Comment: OK. Please avoid to post images: try to copy/paste only text.

Comment: Ok, I will now try to copy/paste that was big so, that's why.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  In order to get the pair of errors you show, your pg_hba.conf must have a hostssl line in it.

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL server log file for a more detailed message about the password failure.  The info sent to the client is intentionally vague to avoid disclosing info to an unauthenticated user.

Comment: I checked, but I found nothing about the password failure. Can you explain more about hostssl line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was using remote heroku database url. After sometime, heroku did maintenance of my database and changed the url and I was considering the problem related to my system, but it was not related to that.

When I visited my gmail there was written in the heroku gmail that we changed the url of your remote database during maintenance.

Now, it's working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Please read following [Heroku support information](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-for-host-user-u-database-d-ssl-off):

> FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "…”, user “u…”, database “d…”,
>   SSL off
>
> You are attempting to establish a database connection without SSL. SSL
>   is required for all connections. Please see the documentation for your
>   postgres driver on how to establish encrypted connections.

Recommended solution:
[Heroku Postgres & SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#heroku-postgres-ssl)

Comment: I am following all the policies, even I reinstalled it but it is still unsolved. Now, this time of installation of postgresql I get another new line may be it's a warning **12  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log**. Please help if you know this!